# Stretch height of nested ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, height, itemscontrol

On MainWindow, I have an `ItemsControl` that I'm adding `UserControls` to, and said `UserControl` also contains an `ItemsControl` containing other `UserControls`.

The problem is that a lot of items in the second ItemsControl aren't showing because they go past the height of the UserControl as it appears on MainWindow.

How can I make sure the UserControls in the first ItemsControl always stretch enough to show all UserControls in their ItemsControl? For trial and error I tried stretching via a ItemTemplate but that didn't change a thing.

```
<Window x:Class="X.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>    
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ic" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

--

```
<UserControl x:Class="X.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="113" Width="209">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ItemsPresenter DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ic" Margin="0,36,0,0" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

--

```
<UserControl x:Class="X.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="40" Width="64">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Label2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Your problem isn't just that both UserControls have Height/Width specified is it (the first one won't stretch)?

Comment: @Chris That actually did the trick.. I thought a usercontrol's width and height only affected design time, could you add this as an answer please?

Comment: Will do, glad that turned out to be the problem. =D

Comment: As a slight followup, you may be able to set your design time height and width using `d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500"`, using the namespace `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" `. Visual Studio 2012 seems to do this by default when creating a new `UserControl`

Comment: @Chris Yeah, that's what it did by default for me as well, but when I resized the window in the GUI editor it apparently changed it from DesignHeight to normal Height which is why it didn't occur to me this was causing it. Thanks for the tip though ;D

Comment: Ah, didn't realise that, I'll keep an eye out next time I resize a window =D Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added from my above comment, which turned out to be the problem.

Your UserControls have `Height` and `Width` explicitly set, which means they won't automatically resize/stretch to accommodate the child controls as you desire.

Removing the `Height` (and ideally `Width`), should do the trick:

```
<UserControl x:Class="X.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" />
    <!-- Your Code -->         
</UserControl>
```